# Rails Wicked PDF - How to download pdf file after a record is saved and continue redirecting as usual?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, wicked-pdf

I'm having a form in which I want to force user to download a pdf file/version using [wicked_pdf](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf) gem of that new record with some content with a submit button called `Save and Download`. For now, the file is downloaded once the user click `Save and Download`, but the page stands still and is not redirected to its show page as usual. I now it should be like this due to my code example below. Yet, I could not figure how to achieve what I want, Save -> Download PDF -> Redirect, or can be Save -> Redirect -> Download PDF.

Let say I'm having an `orders_controller.rb` with the following `actions`.

```
def create
  @order = Order.new(order_params)
  if @order.save
    redirect_to order_path(@order, format: :pdf)
  else
    render :new
  end
end

def show
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html do
      @order = Order.find(params[:id])
    end
    format.pdf do
      render  pdf:      'New Order',
              template: 'orders/show.pdf.haml',
              page_size: 'A4',
              layout:   'pdf_design.haml',
              disposition: 'attachment'
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below bit of code and pass your instance variable in the `locals`.

```
ac = ActionController::Base.new()
pdf_string = ac.render_to_string pdf: 'New Order', template: 'orders/show.pdf.haml', encoding: "UTF-8", locals: {order: @order}
```

Tweak your view in order to assign your local `order` to the view instance variable or directly use `order`

Then assign file like this :

```
file = StringIO.new(pdf_string)
```

And then upload it with whatever gem ( Paperclip, Carrierwave...)

Comment: Thanks, but I want to download, not upload.